# TSQL query using calculation not returning value less than 1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a tsql query that does calculations for percentages, and it calculates fine if the result is > 1, but returns 0 when it is less than 1. My calculation is like so:

```
create table dbo.#temptable ( 
  total_sold int null,
  #_in_ny int null,
  percent_in_ny decimal(18,2)null
) on [primary]

insert into dbo.#temptable    
    select count(t.booknum) as totalsold, t.#_in_ny, 100 * t.#_in_ny / count(t.booknum)
    from mytable t
```

---

That gives me:

```
total   ny sales   %sales in ny
650       4           0     ---- this should show up as 0.61 since 4 is .61% of 650
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that SQL Server does integer division.  The simplest solution is to use `100.0` as the constant:

```
insert into dbo.#temptable    
    select count(t.booknum) as totalsold, t.#_in_ny,
           t.#_in_ny * 100.0 / count(t.booknum)
    from mytable t
```

Comment: does using a float in the constant force sql server to do decimal division?

Answer (score 1):

`t.#_in_ny / count(t.booknum)` - You are doing integer division here. Convert both of these to floats or decimals.

```
insert into dbo.#temptable    
    select count(t.booknum) as totalsold, t.#_in_ny, 100 * CONVERT(float,t.#_in_ny) / CONVERT(float, count(t.booknum))
    from mytable t
```

**EDIT**: See Gordon's answer as well. While either solution works, his is certainly a bit more eloquent than mine.

Comment: You're right, yours' worked as well but Gordon's was simpler. +1 for you though. thanks.